# Is there any other margin I must set to reduce margin to zero?

Tags: margins, document-classes, documentclass-writing

I have basic class file and I would like to set margins of an a4paper to 0mm. Here is the markup of some-class.cls:

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesClass{some-class}[2013/07/29]

\renewcommand{\normalsize}{\fontsize{10pt}{12pt}\selectfont}
\DeclareOption{a4paper}{
    \setlength\paperheight {297mm}%
    \setlength\paperwidth  {210mm}
}
\DeclareOption{landscape} {
    \setlength\@tempdima   {\paperheight}%
    \setlength\paperheight {\paperwidth}%
    \setlength\paperwidth  {\@tempdima}
}

%Default options for design
\ExecuteOptions{a4paper}
%Process user given options
\ProcessOptions

\RequirePackage[top=0mm, bottom=0mm, left=0mm, right=0mm, textwidth=210mm]{geometry}
```

Content of my document.tex:

```
\documentclass[]{some-class}
\author{roncsak}
\title{some title}
\date{2013/07/28}
\begin{document}
Lorem ipsum
\end{document}
```

I would like to set an A4 paper with zero margins. Instead I notice some margin on the left side (approximately 10mm).
I could reduce that margin with the `\RequirePackage[top=0mm, bottom=0mm, left=-10mm, right=0mm, textwidth=210mm]{geometry}` but I would like to understand why this margin left behind.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The most basic approach to obtain a zero-width margin is to use

```
\usepackage[margin=0pt]{geometry}% http://ctan.org/pkg/geometry
```

(or `\RequirePackage` within a class/package). The sets the margins and indirectly also the text block size.

The "margin" you notice is due to the paragraph indent that is set by default to `20pt`. Add `\noindent` to a paragraph to remove this indent, or set it to zero in the preamble using `\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}` which will make the change global.

Comment: The `\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}` worked well! Thank you!

Comment: @roncsak: Don't forget to set a non-zero `\parskip` (or load the package [`parskip`](http://ctan.org/pkg/parskip)) if you set `\parindent` to 0.

Comment: Can the first method (the geometry package) be made to only zero the vertical margins?

Comment: @user4417: Yes. [`geometry`](//ctan.org/pkg/geometry) provides `margin` for *all* margins, `hmargin` for `h`orizontal margins and `vmargin` for `v`ertical margins. You would be interested in `vmargin=0pt` I assume.