# Horizontal Tree Diagram on 4 levels

Tags: horizontal-alignment, trees

I am adapting the answer [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/50418/tools-for-tree-diagram/50426) to create a tree Diagram on 4 levels. I want to create the UML Diagram Types diagram in Latex like this:

[image: UML diagram types]

My code:

```
%https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/50418/tools-for-tree-diagram/50426
%run with xelatex

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pst-tree,array}    
\pagenumbering{gobble}% Remove page numbers (and reset to 1)
\usepackage[margin=0pt]{geometry}% http://ctan.org/pkg/geometry  https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/125937/is-there-any-other-margin-i-must-set-to-reduce-margin-to-zero
\begin{document}
\def\PSB#1{\pspicture(3,1.5)\psTextFrame[shadow,
    fillstyle=solid,linecolor=gray,fillcolor=pink!30,framearc=0.3](0,0)(3,1.5){
        \shortstack{#1}}\endpspicture}

%\pstree{<root>}{<successors>}



\def\psedge#1#2{\ncdiagg[nodesep=3pt,angleA=180,armA=0]{#2}{#1}}
\pstree[treemode=R,levelsep=*1cm]{\Tr{\PSB{Diagram}}}{
\pstree{\Tr{\PSB{Structure\\ Diagram}}}{\Tr{\PSB{Class  Diagram}} \Tr{\PSB{Composite \\ Structure Diagram}} \Tr{\PSB{Component Diagram}} \Tr{\PSB{Deployment Diagram}} \Tr{\PSB{Object Diagram}}   \Tr{\PSB{Package Diagram}}  }
\pstree{\Tr{\PSB{Behaviour\\ Diagram}}}{\pstree{\Tr{\PSB{Barry Santos}}}{\Tr{\PSB{James Kyle}} \Tr{\PSB{Ann Ada}}}}
\pstree{\Tr{\PSB{Behaviour\\ Diagram}}}{\pstree
                            {\pstree{\Tr{\PSB{Barry Santos}}}{\Tr{\PSB{James Kyle}} \Tr{\PSB{Ann Ada}}}}{\Tr{\PSB{James Kyle}} \Tr{\PSB{Ann Ada}}}}

}
\end{document}
```

results in

[image: UML diagram v1]

**How do I add more children to Behavior Diagram?**

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Can be drawn with some other package than `pstree`? For example with TikZ or Forest? Do you like that tree grow horizontally to right?

Comment: Thank you! Can be drawn with any package, as long as I can grow the tree to the right.

Comment: then see, if my answer fulfill your expectation (both enabled grow to any deep level /to the right/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Edit:**
I'm not familiar with `pst-tree` and therefore I can only say that add child node to some child should be done on the same way as was done for child to which you like add child.

With packages `tikz` and `forest`, especial later the construction of trees are relatively simple with well designed structure.

Below are examples with both aforementioned packages. Their structures are partly follows to image, which you show as result of your MWE based on your MWE, partly on guessing what you like to obtain. Hopefully both can serve as starting point to design your real tree.

```
\documentclass[tikz, margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{shadows, trees}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
every node/.style = {draw, rounded corners, fill=red!30,
    text width=18mm, minimum height=9mm, align=center,
    drop shadow},
             grow = right,
level distance = 27mm,
sibling distance=55mm,
growth parent anchor=east,
edge from parent path=(\tikzparentnode.east) -- (\tikzchildnode.west)
                        ]
\node   {Diagram}
    child{  node[yshift=11mm]{?? ??}}
%
    child{  node{Behaviour Diagram}
        [sibling distance=12mm]
        child{  node{Barry Santos}
            child{  node{James Kyle}}
            child{  node{Ann Ada}}
            child{  node{James Kyle}}
            child{  node{Ann Ada}}
             }
        child{  node{???}}
         }
%
    child{  node{Structure Diagram}
        [sibling distance=13mm]
        child{ node{Class  Diagram}}
        child{ node{Composite Structure Diagram}}
        child{ node{Component Diagram}}
        child{ node{Deployment Diagram}}
        child{ node{Object Diagram}}
        child{ node{Package Diagram}}
         }
    ;
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Supremacy of `forest` over `tikz` trees demands more invest into learning, however, it is worth. Final result is nicer, code for placement of children is simpler and concise, etc.

Below are two version of trees, one with forged edges and the second similar as showed with `tikz` solution:

```
\documentclass[tikz, margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{shadows}
\usepackage[edges]{forest}

\begin{document}
   \begin{forest}
    for tree={% style of tree nodes
      draw, semithick, rounded corners, drop shadow,
        top color = red!20,
     bottom color = red!40,
       text width = 18mm, text badly centered,
              % style of tree (edges, distances, direction)
             edge = {draw, semithick},
           anchor = east,
             grow = east,
    forked edge,            % for forked edge
            s sep = 4mm,    % sibling distance
            l sep = 8mm,    % level distance
         fork sep = 4mm,    % distance from parent to branching point
               }
[Diagram
    [?? ??]
%
    [Behaviour Diagram
        [Barry Santos
            [Ann Ada]
            [James Kyle]
            [Ann Ada]
            [James Kyle]
        ]
        [???]
    ]
%
    [Structure Diagram
        [Class  Diagram]
        [Composite Structure Diagram]
        [Component Diagram]
        [Deployment Diagram]
        [Object Diagram]
        [Package Diagram]
    ]
]
    \end{forest}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Here is partly considered OP comment regarding node design:

```
\documentclass[tikz, margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{shadows}
\usepackage[edges]{forest}

\begin{document}
   \begin{forest}
    for tree={% style of tree nodes
      draw, semithick, rounded corners, drop shadow,
        top color = red!20,
     bottom color = red!40,
       text width = 33mm, text badly centered,% <-- "align=center" doesn't work
              % style of tree (edges, distances, direction)
             edge = {draw, semithick},
    parent anchor = east, 
     child anchor = west,
             grow = east,
            s sep = 4mm,    % sibling distance
            l sep = 8mm,    % level distance
               }
[Diagram
    [?? ??]
%
    [Behaviour Diagram
        [Barry Santos
            [Ann Ada]
            [James Kyle]
            [Ann Ada]
            [James Kyle]
        ]
        [???]
    ]
%
    [Structure Diagram
        [Class  Diagram]
        [Composite Structure Diagram]
        [Component Diagram]
        [Deployment Diagram]
        [Object Diagram]
        [Package Diagram]
    ]
]
    \end{forest}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Adapted your solution and it is perfect: `\documentclass[tikz, margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{shadows, trees}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
every node/.style = {draw, rounded corners, fill=blue!40!white,
    text width=35mm, minimum height=9mm, align=center,
    drop shadow},
             grow = right,
level distance = 37mm,
sibling distance=75mm,
growth parent anchor=east,
edge from parent path=(\tikzparentnode.east) -- (\tikzchildnode.west)
                        ]`

Comment: @iulia, with `tikz` tree you need with change of node size -- as you figured out -- also change sibling and level distances. This is not a case with forest. To demonstrate this, I add second solution with forest, where I consider your node size changes. Of course, in `forest` you can use simpler `fill=...` instead of `topcolor=..., bottom color ...`.

Comment: Great answer! There's something that annoys me though, which is the nodes are displayed in the reverse order in which they are declared in the code. This is a bit unintuitive. Is there a way to "fix" this?

Comment: @f10w, sorry i don't understood you. Details about  `forest` package you can find in its documentation. Tree in answer grow just in one direction: to the east. In it is revers order. For more, please ask question and explain what you after. Here are lot experts for `forest` which will happy to help you.